# Scale each element in a list by a corresponding normalizing factor in R

Tags: r, list, data-manipulation

I have a list as follows (each element is a data frame).

```
$E9
   time   response
1:  0.0 0.00000000
2:  0.2 0.00826733
3:  0.4 0.01416873
4:  0.6 0.00845066
5:  0.8 0.01258872
6:  1.0 0.01097368

$F12
   time   response
1:  0.0 0.00000000
2:  0.2 0.00703381
3:  0.4 0.00863728
4:  0.6 0.00739067
5:  0.8 0.00786157
6:  1.0 0.00679848

$H1
   time    response
1:  0.0  0.00000000
2:  0.2  0.00142469
3:  0.4 -0.00418229
4:  0.6  0.00361758
5:  0.8  0.00281592
6:  1.0 -0.00293035
```

I want to multiply each element with a scaling factor, which is stored in a named numeric vector as follows:

```
F12       H1 
1.033911 1.088928
```

For example, I want to multiply the response column of the "F12" element by the element (with the same name) in the vector (1.033911), and if there is no corresponding scaling factor, such as the "E9" element in the list, then I will skip it from being scaled. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list is called `list_df` and numeric vector as `vec` we can use `Map` as :

```
list_df[names(vec)] <- Map(function(x, y) transform(x, response = response * y), 
                           list_df[names(vec)], vec)

list_df
#$E9
#  time response
#1  0.0 0.000000
#2  0.2 0.008267
#3  0.4 0.014169
#4  0.6 0.008451
#5  0.8 0.012589
#6  1.0 0.010974

#$F12
#  time response
#1  0.0 0.000000
#2  0.2 0.007272
#3  0.4 0.008930
#4  0.6 0.007641
#5  0.8 0.008128
#6  1.0 0.007029

#$H1
#  time  response
#1  0.0  0.000000
#2  0.2  0.001551
#3  0.4 -0.004554
#4  0.6  0.003939
#5  0.8  0.003066
#6  1.0 -0.003191
```

**data**

```
list_df <- list(E9 = structure(list(time = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1), 
    response = c(0, 0.00826733, 0.01416873, 0.00845066, 0.01258872, 
    0.01097368)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
)), F12 = structure(list(time = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1), 
    response = c(0, 0.00703381, 0.00863728, 0.00739067, 0.00786157, 
    0.00679848)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
)), H1 = structure(list(time = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1), response = c(0, 
0.00142469, -0.00418229, 0.00361758, 0.00281592, -0.00293035)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)))

vec <- c(F12 = 1.033911, H1= 1.088928)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have that data you describe in a list called `original_list` and the vector with scaling factors in a vector called `scales`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(scale_factors = scales, key = names(scales)) -> 
  scale_factors

tibble(
  values = list,
  key = names(list)) %>%
 left_join(scale_factors) %>%
 mutate(scaled_data = map2(
  .x = values,
  .y = scale_factors,
  ~ mutate(.x, response = response * .y))) ->
 processed_data
```

Comment: ``` ~ mutate(.x, response = response * .y))) ``` a missing bracket at the end :-)